# ActionBar not displaying when extended to listactivity

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, listactivity

as said in the title, I am having problem displaying the actionbar when extended to listactivity.

As you can see below, I have tried requestwindowfeature but it is still not showing.

```
public class AlarmListActivity extends ListActivity {

private AlarmListAdapter mAdapter;
private AlarmDBHelper dbHelper = new AlarmDBHelper(this);
private Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_list);

    mContext = this;

    mAdapter = new AlarmListAdapter(this, dbHelper.getAlarms());
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    //ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    //actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    //actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    //actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.

    -->
</style>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="Divider">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/listDivider</item>
</style>
```

Manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="GOHOME" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="GOHOME" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name="com.example.kaixian.ticmeds.alarmclock.AlarmListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.kaixian.ticmeds.alarmclock.AlarmScreen" />

    <activity android:name="com.example.kaixian.ticmeds.alarmclock.AlarmDetailsActivity" />

    <service android:name="com.example.kaixian.ticmeds.alarmclock.AlarmService"
        android:enabled="true"/>

    <receiver android:name="com.example.kaixian.ticmeds.alarmclock.AlarmManagerHelper" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


</application>
```

Activity_alarm_list.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".AlarmListActivity" >

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Is there a way to show the ActionBar when extending to ListActivity cos I need it to extend to ListActivity. Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Does your activity has menu?

Comment: Post your `styles.xml` file.

Comment: `activity_alarm_list` code?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be adding this to your manifest, to show the ActionBar by default you should use A Holo Theme or one of its descendants  :

```
 <activity
     android:name="com.example.kaixian.ticmeds.alarmclock.AlarmListActivity"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" />
```

If your ActionBar has a menu you can inflate it in your ListActivity like this :

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
     return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
```

I recommend doing both because if you dont add the theme to your Manifest and only inflate via onCreateOptionsMenu() , you might have trouble with displaying your Listactivity properly because it doesnt take care of the paddingTop and so your ActionBar might overlay the top item of your list.